# ConsoleApplication4.exe has stopped working. Windows will close the program and notify if a solution is available

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am newbie to C++ and Visual Studio. I am trying to run and debug code in Visual Studio 2012. But when the code requires some more complex computations VS just crashes like in the example below. After compiling when I click start without debugging I get a pop window displaying the message above. Finally it displays two options debug and close program. When I click on debug it says "unhandled win32 exception occurred in Console application4.exe[5844]". I don't understand what's the issue. When I try to run some simple program such as `std::cout << "something";` it displays the message properly.

```
// ConsoleApplication4.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tbb/blocked_range.h"
#include "tbb/tbb.h"
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "tbb/parallel_for.h"
using namespace tbb;
#define PI 3.14159265

class CL
{
    double * rangeOne;
    double * rangeTwo;

public:
    CL(double * rangeOne, double * rangeTwo) {}

    void operator()(blocked_range<size_t>& r)
        const
    {
        for (size_t i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i)
        {
            rangeOne[i] = sin(i*PI / 180);        
            rangeTwo[i] = cos(i*PI / 180);            
        }
    }


};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double * u = new double[10];
    double * p = new double[10];
    parallel_for(blocked_range<size_t>(0, 10), CL(u, p));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have made a mistake. Finding mistakes is about 80% of programming. Learn how to use a debugger to find your mistakes efficiently.

Comment: I have posted my code. I don't quite understand where's my error

Comment: rangeOne and rangeTwo are uninitialized pointers. beside of that i'm not sure if you really should start with parallel programs. learn the basics and then move on to more complex stuff

Comment: Making a [small example](http://sscce.org/) helps - us and you. Formatting your code has a similar effect.

Comment: Maybe you are right but I don't have much time to get familiar with C++. I have got a project that I need to finish. I come from a Java background and I know how to program.

Comment: @user3149650, Then perhaps you should find a small "C++ for Java Programmers" book. You'll kill yourself trying to guess C++ based on Java.

Comment: @user3149650 Read the following blog post about debugging - this guy usually writes about C#, but debugging is debugging.  I'll also say that `rangeOne` and `rangeTwo` are declared in two scopes - as private member variables in your class, and as parameters in your constructor, with the exact same names. You're also not initializing the member variables with the contents of those parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
CL(double * rangeOne, double * rangeTwo) {}
```

Does not initialize your class variables. It just does nothing. Nothing at all.

It should read:

```
CL(double * rangeOne, double * rangeTwo) : rangeOne(rangeOne), rangeTwo(rangeTwo) {}
```

But please do yourself a big favor and use this error to learn how to use a debugger. This will not be the last error you encounter in your life.

Answer (score 1):

Find out the the point of exception where it is coming by going step by step by F10 and check out on which step exception is coming.

Comment: the code stops at "parallel_for(blocked_range<size_t>(0, 10), CL(u, p));"

And the error I am getting is "Unhandled exception at 0x00904745 in ConsoleApplication5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC."

Comment: this error means that you are trying to access the corrupted or uninitialized variable or array.

Comment: Actually, it means that since you're using an uninitialized pointer (which is pointing somewhere random in memory), you're trying to write to memory that the OS/CPU doesn't think your program should be accessing - hence, access violation.

Comment: you should initialize pointers rangeone and rangetwo. you are using them without initializing.